# An identity with infinite products

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

I do not understand the identity in the box. I tried to rearrange it, but I am not sure how to handle these infinite products.

Comment: Note that every $1 - q^{2m+2n+2}$ is one of the $1 - q^{2m+2}$.  Once you cancel those, what remains is what's on the left side.

Comment: We are requested to see from its previous step.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\prod_{m=0}^\infty\left(1-q^{2m + 2n + 2}\right)}{\prod_{m=0}^\infty\left(1-q^{2m + 2}\right)} = \frac{\color{blue}{(1-q^{2n+2})(1-q^{2n+4})(1-q^{2n+6})\dots}}{(1-q^2)(1-q^4)\dots(1-q^{2n})\color{blue}{(1-q^{2n+2})(1-q^{2n+4})\dots}} $$
$$ = \frac{1}{(1-q^2)(1-q^4)\dots(1-q^{2n})}$$

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.